# How do I get the status bar height in a third party keyboard? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, statusbar

I'm making a keyboard for iOS and need to detect when the status bar changes height in order to be able to update my keyboard accordingly (i.e. when the user gets a call). Unfortunately, `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` is not available in third party extensions and I am unable to get the height this way. Is it possible to grab it in any other way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let navigationController: UINavigationController = .init()
    view.addSubview(navigationController.view)

    let statusBarHeight = navigationController.view.readableContentGuide.layoutFrame.origin.y

    print(statusBarHeight) // 44.0 (iPhone X) / 20.0 (iPhone SE)

    navigationController.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: And where does this `navigationController` come from?

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: Sorry! This code works in my project. I will reproduce this in an empty project and update my message.